# Where can I find the Heroes of Rokugan 1 modules?

Tags: published-adventures, l5r

I have found the Heroes of Rokugan website but only modules from Campaign 3 seems to be available on it. Does anyone either know where Campaigns1 and 2 are, or how I can get hold of them? Specifically I'm hoping for anything from before the scorpion clan coup in the timeline, or anything I can amend and use for this period.

I have now been in contact with one of the hosts of HoR and it has been confirmed that the earlier campaigns are not available on the website as they do not hold the rights. Where can I find modules from Heroes of Rokugan 1 and Heroes of Rokugan 2?

Comment: Heroes of Rokugan 1 was originally called 'Living Rokugan', and was run initially via the RPGA. I have two of the scenarios from the time, but that's it. I've been unable to find much more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My husband created HoR, and ran HoR1 and HoR2.  So here's the story:
The legal rights of HoR 1 are very uncertain.  The modules comprising the first 40% were purchased by WoTC back when it was in the RPGA, and theoretically they still own them.  Without getting lawyers involved its impossible to say how the purchase of L5R by FFG from AEG affects this.  Therefore, no one really wants to take on the big companies and risk getting lawyers set on them by hosting the material that Wizards can claim copyright to.  That left players begging people who had personal copies for years, unfortunately.

For HoR2, heroes-of-rokugan.com is now defunct.  Kazenoshiro has changed the path, so just check the [Content Archive](https://kazenoshiro63445525.wordpress.com/content-archive/) for a link.

The modules will shortly [at the time of writing this answer] be available at http://www.robhobart.com

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any place online where to find HOR 1 scenarios.

However there are at least 2 sites that have the HOR 2 scenarios :

[heroes-of-rokugan.com](http://heroes-of-rokugan.com/HoR2/index.html)

and

[Kazenoshiro.com](http://www.kazenoshiro.com/heroes-of-rokugan-ii/)

Comment: The heroes-of-rokugan.com scenario list page is [archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150103114841/http://heroes-of-rokugan.com/HoR2/scenarios.html), but the download links no longer work (the original site is down). [Here's the Content Archive page](https://kazenoshiro63445525.wordpress.com/content-archive/) of the latter site, which has moved to a WordPress blog.